# how can i pass float array from .php file to javascript function in .html file. i need this vaules for ploting map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I want to catch these lat,lng,and inf arrays inside javascript in html and then want to plot a map

```
while ($obj = $res->fetch_object())  // get all rows (markers)
{<br>
    $lat[$mrk_cnt] = $obj->lat;  // save the lattitude<br>
    $lng[$mrk_cnt] = $obj->lng;  // save the longitude<br>
    $inf[$mrk_cnt] = $obj->MAXTEMP;  // save the info-window<br>
    $mrk_cnt++;                      // increment the marker counter<br>
}
<br>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make an ajax call from your html file to the php file and store the result in javascript array.

A link to Ajax turotial: 
http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/

Comment: i just used session variable :D

Comment: i see but you might be using php file then not HTML because you can't use php if the file format is html

Answer (score 0):

you can pass php array into java script into html file

```
<script>
  var lat= <?php echo json_encode($lat); ?>
 var lng= <?php echo json_encode($lng); ?>
 var inf= <?php echo json_encode($inf); ?>
</script>
```

Comment: how will my script know...from which php file these arrays are coming?

Comment: you can't access PHP tags in HTML